# Selenium webdriver Exceptional

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

**Getting this exceptional**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at dT.Dt.main(Dt.java:21)
```

Comment: version of geckodriver driver?

Comment: It is an ordinary exception, not an exceptional exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use geckodriver to interact with Firefox since Selenium 3.0. 
Download the geckodriver.exe.

And then add the below code before driver initialization.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:/your/path/to/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks !! It works ..